# Increase PHPlot DPI/PPI

Tags: php, laravel, php-gd, phplot

I am constructing a new PHPlot object with `$graph = new PHPlot_truecolor(500, 350);`. The 500x350 dimensions give me the correct size, however, the graph is very pixelated and I need it to be print quality. I can’t bump the resolution because then everything becomes very small and does not scale. Ideally, I would just be able to increase the PPI. I’m using Laravel and tried

```
$graph->SetCallback('draw_setup', function ($img) {
    imageantialias($img, True);
    imageresolution($img, 300, 300);
});
```

but go the error: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\imageresolution()`. Changing the second line of the anonymous function to `\imageresolution($img, 300, 300);` to escape the namespace just yields `Call to undefined function imageresolution()`.

I’m really not sure why `imageantialias` works but `imageresolution` doesn't when they’re in the same package. If anyone knows the cause or a better way to change the PPI, that would be much appreciated

Comment: According to manual `imageresolution` is avaialble since __php7.2__. So check your php version.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you so much! I was on 7.1, not sure why PHPStorm didn’t catch that when I had it set to that version for syntax checking. It didn’t actually help improve the quality of my image but at least it’s compiling haha. If you want the points for the accepted answer, just answer it and I’ll accept

Comment: You can answer your question yourself, I'm a bit lazy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @u_mulder, it turns out that the [`imageresolution`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php) function is only available in PHP 7.2 or greater, when I was running 7.1